# Preview mode in google tag manger

Tags: google-analytics

I active preview mode in Google tag manager but preview pane doesn't show in website tab?
whats the problem?

Comment: Does your website preview in Google Fetch and Render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:  an ad blocker extension prevented the preview pane from opening.